# Hadith on someone biting their father's genitals

Tags: hadith

Can someone shed some light on this hadith:

> Ubayy b. Ka‘b told that he heard God’s messenger say, “If anyone
> proudly asserts his descent in the manner of the pre-Islamic people,
> tell him to bite his father’s penis, and do not use a euphemism.”
>
> Mishkat al-Masabih Vol 2, 1021

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/121823/

Answer (score -1):

ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ ٱللَّٰهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

This hadīth was classified as Da'īf (weak) by Shaykh Zubayr 'Alī Za'ī'.

سندہ ضعیف، رواہ البغوي في شرح السنۃ (120/13۔ 121 ح 3541) [و أحمد (136/5) والبخاري فی الأدب المفرد (936، 946)]
٭ الحسن البصري عنعن و للحدیث شواھد ضعیفۃ عند عبد اللہ بن أحمد فی زوائد المسند (133/5، فیہ مدلس و عنعن) وغیرہ .